Package Resource Mapping is enabled but no resources were found under the specified package
I want to install dotnet-ef.
I get an error when I enter the following command into the terminal.
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.0.3
Package Resource Mapping is enabled but no resources were found under the specified package ID: dotnet-ef. For more details on Package Resource Mapping, see the documentation https://aka.ms/nuget-package-source-mapping.


Just started getting this myself which is weird because I didn't change any settings. Did you figure it out?

No, I couldn't figure it out.

Make sure your %appdata%/nuget/NuGet.Config contains the dotnet-ef nuget package entry, like this:
<configuration>
  <packageSourceMapping>
    <package pattern="dotnet-ef" />

